# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested version 3)?

Tags: cmake, openpose

When I run the **cmake** to build openpose, the error message as below comes out.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:415 (find_package): Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested version 3) with any of the following names: Eigen3Config.cmake eigen3 config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Eigen3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

In the CMakeLitsts.txt file, the 415 line is like this

```
 find_package(Eigen3 3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
```

How can I start to solve? Any idea on what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: "How can I start to solve?" - You may start to solve by reading given error message. It tells about installation of Eigen3, so the first obvious question: whether do you have Eigen3 installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading the package and built on Cmake alone first.(Configure, Generate, and open with VS2019 under administrator rights so when  executing ALL_BUILD and INSTALL it would write files to disk C). Then add the Eigen3_DIR to system path. Reboot the project that didn't find Eigen3 earlier on Cmake,  problem disappeared.